# Problema al actualizar

Tags: c#, oracle

Necesito actualizar una tabla en Oracle el campo status a Denied, teniendo en cuenta el ultimo ID obtenido.

```
 string update = "UPDATE TABLA1 SET STATUS = DENIED WHERE :ID =" + id;
```

Al pasar por esa linea, y chechar si se hizo el cambio, no esta actualizado, que podra ser?

Comment: Hola, ¿Será que DENIED es un string y deberías poner 'DENIED' y no DENIED ?

Comment: Tambien le puse esas comillas e igual no hace nada.

Comment: ¿Y probaste la consulta directamente en el Oracle GUI?

Comment: si lo pongo asi UPDATE TABLA1 SET STATUS= 'denied' WHERE ID = 119; dice que se actualizo sin embargo voy a la tabla y sigue igual

Comment: Raro.... ¿podria ser problemas de permisos?

Comment: Si el UPDATE lo realizas con una conexión y el SELECT con otra, puedes ser que no has hecho COMMIT de la transacción del UPDATE y por eso el SELECT aún no lo ve.

Answer (score 0):

No defines de forma correcta el parametro `Id` que usas el el `update`

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("connection string")) 
{
    conn.Open();

    string update = "UPDATE TABLA1 SET STATUS = DENIED WHERE ID = :ID";
   OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(update, conn);

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ID", id));

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

como veras en la coleccion de  `Parameters` del command es donde asignas el valor

Haya otra forma de definirlo si quieres indicar el tipo de datos

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(":ID", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = id;
```